# JavaScript function - named parameters issue when skipping an optional parameter

Tags: javascript, named-parameters

If you run the below code in browser's console:

```
function named_param(a, b=null, c=5) {
  console.log("a="+a);
  console.log("b="+b);
  console.log("c="+c);
}

named_param(3, c=10)
```

The output received is:

```
a=3
b=10
c=5
```

The output I am looking for, is:

```
a=3
b=null
c=10
```

I saw the below two URLs and tried a few workaround but it didn't work

[Javascript Function Parameters Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231150/javascript-function-parameters-not-working)

[Named parameters in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/named-parameters-in-javascript)

Let me know the steps I am doing wrong here. Tried the below codes but didn't work:
A:

```
function named_param(a, {b=null, c=5}) {
  console.log("a="+a);
  console.log("b="+b);
  console.log("c="+c);
}

named_param(3, c=10)
```

B:

```
function named_param(a, {b=null, c=5}={}) {
  console.log("a="+a);
  console.log("b="+b);
  console.log("c="+c);
}

named_param(3, c=10)
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have named parameters. Please try running `named_param(3, c=10)` in strict mode and you'll get an exception.

Comment: The "*Javascript Function Parameters Not Working*" question has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the destructuring solution, you must pass an actual object. `named_param(3, c=10)` simply is invalid syntax (well, it's valid, but it's an assignment to a global `c` variable that is passed as the second argument - no naming).

```
function named_param(a, {b=null, c=5}={}) {
  console.log("a="+a);
  console.log("b="+b);
  console.log("c="+c);
}
```

```
named_param(3)
named_param(3, {b:"hi"})
named_param(3, {c:10})
named_param(3, {b:"hi", c:10})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip parameter in between, so when you pass

```
named_param(3, c=10)
            |   |_____________ considered as `b`
            |_________________ considered as `a`
```

You can use object and destructuring

```js
function named({a,b=null,c=3} = {}){
  console.log('a-->',a)
  console.log('b-->',b)
  console.log('c-->',c)
}

named({a:1,c:2})
named()
named({c:2})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is something using destructuring objects like:

```
function named_params({a = 4, b = null, c = 5} = {a:1, b: 2, c:3}) { console.log(a,b,c) }
```

then, the call for your function will be:

```
named_params({a: 3, c:10})
```

Comment: Having different default values for `name_params()` vs `name_params({})` is weird

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's not an issue, it's just you trying to use named parameters where they are not supported at all.

To reach what you need, you should do like this:

```
function named_param({a, b, c}) {
  console.log("a="+a);
  console.log("b="+b);
  console.log("c="+c);
}

named_param({a:5, c:9}); 
// Output:
// a=5
// b=undefined
// c=9
```

At first I misunderstood your question and proposed to use destructuring assignment with `arguments` object.